# Integrating rails with wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, paypal

I trying to integrate a current wordpress woocomerce website with a rails app. 
I need to figure out with the best way to do two things:

1. Fetch, Create, update and delete products/posts with all the taxonomies and fields in the wordpress woocomerce website from my rails app.
2. Know when an order was did from paypal in the wordpress woocomerce website and then update my rails app.(already woocomerce know when the order was did and then update their wp tables)

I will appreciate if anyone could help me or show me the right way to do this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was originally going to write about using an [API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) for this, however, I think there's a better way - to **hook into the WP table from Rails**

From what you've written (which doesn't give much context btw), it seems you're looking for some way to manage your products & orders independently of Wordpress. Perhaps you want to integrate the data into a CRM, or you want to create an order-tracking system; it all needs data

---

**Data**

There are two ways to do it:

1. Create independent Rails app & port data with an API
2. Build the Rails app on top of the Wordpress db

---

**API**

An API will be best if you want to keep your data separate (you have sensitive data / you want to migrate to a total Rails solution)

You'll need to create your db through `Rails`, and then use a `RESTful` `API` interface to process `JSON` strings of all the products from `WP`. You'd have to send the objects by either a plugin, or a cron-job running a simple script to comb the database every night

As you can guess, this will be the least efficient way of doing it, but the most robust. You'd have two data-sets, and any updates in `WP`'s table structure will have to be reflected in your `Rails` implementation

---

**Wordpress**

The better way to do this will be to hook into the `Wordpress` `db` directly

The problem here is that you'll effectively be managing two database systems (`Rails` likes to run off its own db), so you'll have to manage `user` profiles etc from the Rails DB, whilst hooking into the products db in Wordpress

Although I've got zero experience with this, I found some resources which may help:

- [Ruby on Rails Integration With Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277531/ruby-on-rails-integration-with-wordpress)
- [Searching WordPress blog from Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114081/searching-wordpress-blog-from-rails-app)

Hope this gives you some ideas!